# Can I send an email that will reach a Twitter account?

Tags: email, twitter

There is a new restaurant across town I want to make a reservation at, but they only have a Twitter account (no email or phone number listed). I don't use Twitter and don't want to make an account just to ask whether they take reservations. Does Twitter have some static email for each account that I can send an email message, and it will show up on their Twitter “homepage”?

I know nothing about Twitter and googled my question with no luck.

Comment: I wish too that Twitter supported such a scenario, but I don't think posting to someone else's Twitter account is possible without an account as Twitter & the recipient will not know who sent the message. The email sent from would need to be validated and it would also change the rules of their game.

Answer (score 3):

I very much doubt it:

You most probably don't want your message "Please make a reservation for Jane Doe, phone 123-4567" to show on their public twitter-feed for everyone to see.

Twitter's equivalent to email (private messaging) is Direct Messaging.  However Twitter users can (only) "... send a message to anyone who follows [them]."   This rule isn't stated in their help, but is shown when a Twitter user goes to the DM function.

And if you think about it - opening up a Twitter user's account to receive spam from unidentified phone numbers really wouldn't do good things for that person's sanity!

Answer (score 0):

There are integrations services you could do this with (e.g. Zapier) or apps like [Wax](https://www.wax.run/twitter) that are specifically for this type of thing.